# deleted gpg key (secret and public) now I can't send emails in emacs mu4e

Tags: emacs, gnupg

I lost a password of my key, so I deleted it now emacs complains when I send a mail via mu4e.

I deleted my entire ~/.gnupg directory

I regenerated the ~/.authinfo.gpg key via `epa-encrypt-file`

I receive this message when sending an email :

Error while decrypting with "/usr/bin/gpg2":

gpg: encryped with rsa key, identifier 332E4EA69190BEBA
gpg: failed to decrypt : No secret key

Comment: What is your question? You cannot send encrypted email, if you delete the key, you were using to encrypt emails

Comment: Do I need to recreate a key ? I didn't have to do that on my other computers

Comment: Recreating the key wouldn't do much if you are not using the same key.  You need to replace the key with the new key.  I assume the key identifier you forgot the password to was 332E4EA69190BEBA?

Comment: yes, the key was 332E4EA69190BEBA

Comment: I created a new key, how do I replace the old key with the new key ?